# Google Places update via API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Do you know if it is possible to update an existing place via API in Google Places?

Suppose I need to change the "Hours of operation" because my business activity has flexible open hours and I want to automate this task via script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Google Palces API decoumentation tells only about deleting or adding new places:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

So it seems impossible for now, but it is still beta, so maybe it will be possible in future.